# Как сделать чтобы слайдер работал корректно (React + OwlCarousel)?

Tags: reactjs, owl-carousel

Ребята подскажите, на мультиязычной (2 языка) странице есть компонент, в виде слайдера (OwlCarousel). На каждом слайде есть текст. В компонент залетает переменная locale через props. При инициализации (начальной загрузке) язык правильный на слайдах. Но при первом переключении языка, в слайдах, текст не меняется (переключ.языка не происходит), а лишь при последующих переключениях происходит смена текста на др.язык, НО! с отставанием в один шаг, то есть когда на странице один язык, в слайдах другой язык???!!!

Для проверки вынес текст за пределы слайдера - все работает отлично!!! Текст и язык синхронно переключаются!!!

Код ниже...

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
import { contextHomeSl } from '../data/db_home_sl_offer';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';

function Homepage(props) {
    const { locale } = props;

    return (
        <main id={'home-page'}>
            {/* :: Header | Offer */}
            <header className='header header-home-1' id='page'>
                <OwlCarousel
                    className='header-owl owl-carousel owl-theme'
                    nav
                    navSpeed
                    margin={10}
                    loop
                    autoplayHoverPause
                    autoplayTimeout={4000}
                    smartSpeed={1000}
                    autoplay={false}
                    animateOut={'fadeOut'}
                    animateIn={'fadeIn'}
                    dotsSpeed
                    mouseDrag
                    touchDrag
                    navText={[
                        '<i className="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                        '<i className="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i>'
                    ]}
                    responsive={{
                        0: { items: 1 },
                        768: { items: 1 },
                        991: { items: 1 }
                    }}
                >
                    {contextHomeSl.map((itemDetail) => {
                        const { id } = itemDetail;

                        return (
                            <div key={id} className={`sec-hero item display-table header-bg-${id}`}>
                                <div className='table-cell'>
                                    <div className='overlay'></div>
                                    <div className='container'>
                                        <div className='row'>
                                            <div className='col-lg-8'>
                                                <div className='banner animated fadeInUp'>
                                                    <div className='headline-top'>
                                                        <p>{locale === 'en' ? 'Privet' : 'Привет'}</p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </OwlCarousel>
                <p>{locale === 'en' ? 'Privet' : 'Привет'}</p>
            </header>
            
        </main>
    );
}

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: а как в родителе locale меняете?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт! Просто перепрошил на другой слайдер - Swiper!
И все заработала сразу!

Comment: @Зонтик, а других ответов-то нет )

Comment: @wchistow просто из очереди чтобы посмотреть ответы, нужно нажать кнопочку "Другие ответы". А я что-то и не заметил, что таковой нет :)